# How to reach files in a previously windows installed hdd

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8, external-hard-drive

Here is the situation:

My friend's windows 8 installed computer screwed up and we want to recover the data (hdd is working properly)

We took the hdd and connected it to another windows 8 installed computer (both 64 bits). We are able to reach user files (desktop, documents etc.) however, somehow, not all of the files are visible. And hdd capacity is shown as 297GB althoug hdd is 500GB in real.

Can you suggest me something to recover my friend's files?

Comment: Sounds like bad sectors. You may be able to recover some of the files using one of the disk drive recovery tools like SpinRite.

Comment: chkdsk /f :X  says no bad sactors

Comment: Only one partition mounting?

Comment: @Kazark both of them gets mounted but their spaces are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would second @EBGreen's comment that it sounds like the reason for the failure of the first machine was due to a disk error.

I'd also recommend [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com) that many people, including myself, have used to great effect to recover seemingly destroyed disks. It's not free, about USD90 but worth it if it is the only way to get the data back.

Checkdisk can't always spot errors.